# Clarification regarding Postfix Increment Operator ++ :java

Tags: java

```js
int i = 0;
boolean b = true;
System.out.println(b && !(i++ > 0))
```

When I compile the above code I get a value true back.

But how can that be, since the second part of the argument (since b is true already) basically translates to

`(0 + 1 > 0) => (1 > 0)`

which should return `true`. Then the statement would be `true && false`, which is `false`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java behaving correctly :)

```
i++
```

That is **postfix** increment.

It generated result and then incremented that value later.

```
!(i++ > 0) // now  value is still zero
```

`i++` will use the previous `value` of `i` and then it will `increment` it.

When you use ++ ,it's like

```
temp=i;
i += 1; 
i=temp;     // here old value of i.
```

[language specification on  Postfix Increment Operator ++](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)

> the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable.  ......
>
> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable before the new value is stored.

Possible solution would be `++i`, which is as per your requirment,

> [Prefix Increment Operator ++](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1)
>
> The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the variable after the new value is stored.

Comment: Thank you! It's challenging to keep track of all these details, but nevertheless, I will try to search even more extensively next time. I was just baffled by the result!!

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `++i` if you want to increment i and return the incremented value. `i++` returns the non incremented value.

Answer (score 2):

```
b && !(i++ > 0)
```

`i++` is post increment so value of i here is still 0

`0>0` false

`b && 1` is true(since `!(0)` is 1)

So you are getting true.

Answer (score 1):

```
i++
```

the increment happens after the line is executed
so you better keep

```
++i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see how ++ operator works on following example:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    int zero = 0;
    System.out.println(zero++);
    zero = 0;
    System.out.println(++zero);
}
```

Result is:
    0
    1