# Increase value of byte array contents

Tags: java

I wan't to be able to increase the value of content in my byte array.

For example if in my array I have got the value `1100001` what is an effective way of incrementing this value so that the contents of the array would show `1100010`.

I thought that it would be something like the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
ByteArray[i] = ByteArray[i]++;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [You are confused with ++i and i++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375089/clarification-regarding-postfix-increment-operator-java/19375115#19375115)

Comment: show us more code... what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ByteArray[i] = ByteArray[i]++;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
byte temp = ByteArray[i];
ByteArray[i]++;
ByteArray[i] = temp;
```

In other words, you're increasing the value, then replacing it with the old value.

What you want is either

```
ByteArray[i]++;
```

or

```
ByteArray[i] = ByteArray[i] + 1;
```

Comment: or `ByteArray[i] += 1;` as long as we're including everything

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick response

Answer (score 2):

`x++` returns the *original* value of `x`.
You're then assigning the original value back to the array slot.

Comment: this is right, but OP seems to be a beginner. please explain it more

Comment: And it doesn't answer author's question, nor solve his problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should read into increment operators, there is `++x` and `x++`. Both increment, but `++x` returns x+1, while `x++` returns x.

This in your case, you set ByteArray[i] to ByteArray[i], the increment is impatiently overwritten.

Use `ByteArray[i]++;` instead.

And whenever you use the return of such an increment, think about which variant you use.

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick response